# Prove every 4th Fibonacci number is divisible by 3 using mathematical Induction?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, fibonacci-numbers

Can anyone confirm whether my answer is correct, please.

Let's suppose we have the following fibonacci numbers as shown: $f(0) = 0, f(1)  = 1$, and  $f(n) = f(n-1) + f(n-2)$ for $n \geq 2$. Prove that for each $n \geq 0, f(4n)$ is a multiple of $3$

$f_0 = 0,f_1= 1,f_n = f_{n-1}+f_{n-2} \text{ for } n \geq 2$ Prove that for each $n \geq 0, f_{4n}$ is a multiple of $3$.

### My solution to this question:

\begin{align}
f_{4(k+1)} & = f_{4k+4} \\
& = f_{4k+3} + f_{4k+2} \\
& = f_{4k+3} + (f_{4k+1} + f_{4k}) \\
& = (f_{4k+2} + f_{4k+1}) + (f_{4k+1} + f_{4k}) \\
& = f_{4k+1} + f_{4k} + f_{4k+1} + f_{4k+1} + f_{4k} \\
& = 3(f_{4k+1}) + 2(f_{4k})
\end{align}

Comment: $f_{4(k+1)}=f_{4k+4}$ rest is ok.

Comment: You need to demonstrate that it is true for $n=1$

Comment: Prove by induction: 1. Show that $f_4$ is a multiple of $3$. 2. Assume that $f_{4n}$ is a multiple of $3$. 3. Use this assumption in order to prove that $f_{4(n+1)}$ is a multiple of $3$. Your last statement doesn't clearly show it. You need to extract $3$ as a common factor, i.e., write something like $=3(f_{4k+1}+2q)$, where $q=\frac{f_{4k}}{3}\in\mathbb{N}$.

Comment: I skipped the base step part, but I see what you mean there. Thanks!

Comment: [In fact](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fibonacci_number#Divisibility_properties) $f(k)|f(kn)$, so $f(4)=3|f(4n)$.

Answer (score 1):

What you need to prove is that $f_{4(n + 1)}$ is divisible by 3 (or that it has a factor of 3 in it) for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$. You have to prove that the proposition holds for your base case: $f_4$ which it surely does.
Now you assume $f_{4n}$ holds and prove that $f_{4(n + 1)}$ also holds.

To do this, define $f_{4n} = 3m, \hspace{2mm} m \in \mathbb{N}$, (definition of multiple of 3).

Now, we have to construct $f_{4(n + 1)}$, Fibonacci numbers are defined by their predecesors in the form:

$$ f_n = f_{n - 1} + f_{n - 2}$$

We also define $f_{4n - 1} = k, \hspace{2mm} k \in \mathbb{N}$ (this just tells us that it is a natural number, as $F \subset \mathbb{N}$).

We can now procede to construct $f_{4(n + 1)}$ as follows:

$$ f_{4n + 1} = f_{4n} + f_{4n - 1} = 3m + k $$

$$ f_{4n + 2} = f_{4n + 1} + f_{4n} = (3m + k) + (3m) = (6m + k)$$

$$ f_{4n + 3} = f_{4n + 2} + f_{4n + 1} = (6m + k) + (3m + k) = (9m + 2k)$$

$$ f_{4n + 4} = f_{4n + 3} + f_{4n + 2} = (9m + 2k) + (6m + k) = (15m + 3k)$$

Now, we can factor out 3 in the last step:

$$ f_{4n + 4} = 3(5m + k)$$

but $ f_{4n + 4} = f_{4(n + 1)} $, we showed that if the proposition for $f_{4n}$ holds, it also holds for $ f_{4(n + 1)}$

Answer (score 0):

Calculating $f(n)$ **mod** $3$ up to $n = 9$ gives

| $n$ | 0 | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 | 6 | 7 | 8 | 9 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| $f(n)$ **mod** $3$ | **0** | **1** | **1** | **2** | **0** | **2** | **2** | **1** | **0** | **1** |

This shows

1. $f(0) \equiv f(4) \equiv 0$ **mod** $3$
2. $f(n+8) \equiv f(n)$ **mod** $3$
3. $f(4n) \equiv 0$ **mod** $3$